# How to properly configure squid outgoing tcp address?

Tags: proxy, routes, ip, reverse-proxy, squid

I'm new to proxies.

I have installed squid and I have two ip addresses right now.

104.255.115.114 (default)
104.255.115.115 (additional)

I want to set squid to use non default address.

I've entered to config:

**tcp_outgoing_address 104.255.171.115**

However, when trying to browse via squid, it uses an IPV6 address and the sites also detect I have proxy on the 104.255.115.115 address.

**Edit:** This is how http://www.ip-adress.eu/ shows it:

My IP address is 127.0.0.1
localhost.localdomain
Proxy detected: 104.255.115.115 (104.255.171.115)

So obviously, it doesn't work.

How can I make it actually use the 104.255.115.115 address and make my browsing anonymous?

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding anonymous proxy headers from
http://nikhgupta.com/code/setting-up-anonymous-proxy-with-squid/

and then disabled ipv6 in my network adapter ! :-)